# How do I set a default (non-hard coded) Availability Zone in a CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write a CloudFormation script and have the person executing it choose the AZ's they want to use from a dropdown list with the first one pre-selected as the default. Getting the list of AZ's hasn't been a problem, but getting the first one selected by default hasn't been so straight forward.

The following seems like it should work:

```
  AvailabilityZones: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name
    Default:
      - !Select 
        - 0
        - !GetAZs 
          Ref: 'AWS::Region'
```

However, the error I get back is "Template format error: Every Default member must be a string.".  However, nothing I have done to date gives me anything useful. Every example I have found on-line ends up with a hardcoded value and that's what I'm trying to avoid.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible without a [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) that you have to develop for your template.